# Docusaurus error during building the project

Tags: docusaurus

First of all let me say that I'm new of Docusaurus and I'm using version 2.

I was building my documentation project and I have got the following error:

```
Docusaurus Node/SSR could not render static page with path=/docs/My_MDX_Page because of error: useBaseUrl is not defined
```

I'm using a MDX page to get the baseURL to retrieve static contents.

The MDX page:

```
---
title: title
hide_title: true
sidebar_label: item
---
import useBaseUrl from '@docusaurus/useBaseUrl';

## Section

| Name | image |
| :--- | :--- |
| YL_GN3 | <img src={useBaseUrl('img/YL_GN3.png')} /> |
```

I think I'm doing something wrong even if executing without building it works (by npm start).

Comment: Hi - I just want to verify that you ran `yarn install` or `npm install` first before trying this. I think you have, but let's just start there. Can you provide the directory structure of your installation?

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` was executed.

Here is the directory structure of project:

```
+ .docusaurus 
+ build 
+ docs 
+ node_modules 
+ src 
+ static 
+ versioned_docs 
+ versioned_sidebars 
babel.config.js 
docusaurus.config.js 
package-lock.json 
package.json 
README.md 
sidebars.js 
versions.json
```

**UPDATE**
For reasons that I don't know, it has started working. I have changed docusaurs config, adding the baseUrl different from '/' and 'index.js' in order to have the docs as landing page

Comment: I was having a similar problem, even after reverting to known good check-in. What finally "fixed' it was exiting the terminal I was in and trying a new one. Like yourself, I have no idea what changed in that regard. It's almost like the terminal was 'stuck' (despite my using yarn clear, even).

Comment: Hey, apparently, restarting IDE/text editor resolve the issue.